# How to enable different GL_POSITION of two objects

Tags: c, opengl, glut, lighting, opengl-compat

[image]

I want to create two objects with different light position. But the light position of second object (Gold sphere) is always the same as the first object (Silver sphere) even I have set different position parameter.

I have enable both light one after another object. But the second one is always the same as the first/above one.

```
    // light from top right
    GLfloat light_position_top_right[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
    // light from bottom left
    GLfloat light_position_bottom_left[] = { -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position_top_right);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, light_position_bottom_left);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

You can find complete code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/PirunSeng/91740a3f20c5404ebd58d9adc0a22cd1).

I expect the second object to have light position from bottom left. But it shows from top right as the first object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth coordinate of your light positions must be `1.0` instead of `0.0`, otherwise due to how projective transformations work the lights will behave as if they are infinitely far away in the specified direction.

With a fourth coordinate of `0.0`:

[image: Lights are infinitely far away]

With a fourth coordinate of `1.0`:

[image: Lights are properly located]

As for why there are two highlights instead of just one, you forgot to set the proper `glLight*` settings for your lights. By default, `GL_LIGHT0` begins with white diffuse and specular color, but all other lights have black diffuse and specular color by default.

---

**EDIT:**

If you want separate spheres to use separate lights, you'll need to initialize the lights during `init()`. But instead of `glEnable`ing the lights right then, do the following:

```
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(1.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    drawGraySphere();
    glutSolidSphere(0.5, 50, 50);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-0.75, -0.8, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
    drawGoldSphere();
    glutSolidSphere(0.5, 50, 50);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT1);
    glPopMatrix();

    glFlush();
}
```

Alternatively, you have the option to just use a single light, and change its parameters using `glLight*` each frame, before rendering each sphere. This is the better option if you plan on having a bunch of objects, each with their own light.

Comment: Sorry, but not so clear. `GLfloat light_position_top_right[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };` and `GLfloat light_position_bottom_left[] = { -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };`
I've updated the fourth coordinate, but the result is not as expected.

Comment: I've just updated my gist by adding my expectation.

Comment: Ah, you want to use GL_LIGHT0 for the first object and GL_LIGHT1 for the second object? In that case you need to use `glEnable(GL_LIGHT*)` and `glDisable(GL_LIGHT*)` between both objects properly. Don't worry, you don't need to set the light parameters again after reenabling them.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just reuse `GL_LIGHT0` all the time and always set the parameters as necessary between objects.

Comment: Yes, my first object is GL_LIGHT0, and second object is GL_LIGHT1. However, I try enable and disable light as this, but no luck. It has no light at all.
`glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);glDisable(GL_LIGHT1);glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`

Comment: Interesting, but could you provide a complete code with the functions please? Because I'm still having issue for the light, and I'm not clear which should I keep/remove from the `init()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code, modified to do what you want it to do:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void drawGoldSphere() {
    GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 0.628281, 0.555802, 0.366065, 1.0 };
    GLfloat mat_shininess[] = { 51.2 };
    GLfloat mat_ambient[] = { 0.24725, 0.1995, 0.0745, 1.0 };
    GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { 0.75164, 0.60648, 0.22648, 1.0 };
    //Material Properties
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, mat_ambient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
}

void drawGraySphere() {
    GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat mat_shininess[] = { 50.0 };
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
}

void init(void)
{
    // light from middle left
    //GLfloat light_position[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    // light from top right
    GLfloat light_position_top_right[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
    // light from bottom left
    GLfloat light_position_bottom_left[] = { -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
    // light from bottom left
    //GLfloat light_position[] = { -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, 0.0 };
    // light from middle top
    //GLfloat light_position[] = { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    // light from middle right
    //GLfloat light_position[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    // light from middle middle
    //GLfloat light_position[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
    // light from middle bottom
    //GLfloat light_position[] = { 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };


    GLfloat no_mat[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat light_diffuse[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat light_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat high_shininess[] = { 100.0 };

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position_top_right);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, light_position_bottom_left);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(1.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    drawGraySphere();
    glutSolidSphere(0.5, 50, 50);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-0.75, -0.8, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
    drawGoldSphere();
    glutSolidSphere(0.5, 50, 50);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT1);
    glPopMatrix();

    glFlush();
}
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    if (w <= h)
    glOrtho(-1.5, 1.5, -1.5*(GLfloat)h/(GLfloat)w,
    1.5*(GLfloat)h/(GLfloat)w, -10.0, 10.0);
    else
    glOrtho(-1.5*(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h,
    1.5*(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h, -1.5, 1.5, -10.0, 10.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Render result:

[image]